# Approximations for real functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, real-analysis

Is there some set of real functions ($S$) that has precisely the cardinality of the continuum, but is dense in the space of all the real functions in a sense that every real function can be approximated by the functions from this set as closely as needed?

In a sense that for any real number $\varepsilon >0$ and subset of reals $D \neq\Bbb R$, and any real function $f(x)$ there is $g(x)$ from the $S$, s.t. $\lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $x$ in $D$.

Value of approximating in $D$ can be seen in, for example, this way of approximating Dirichlet function: define $n$-th approximation as $g(n,x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{for all rationals with denominator less or equal to $n$;} \\
0 & \text{for all inputs between those rationals.}
\end{cases}$ Notice that $g(n,x)$ is always Riemann-integrable since it is continous everywhere except on countable amount of inputs. Limit of $g(n,x)$ as $n$ goes to infinity is Dirichlet function of $x$, proof of that is similar to the Dedekind cut construction of reals. And by this definition of approximation: $\lvert1_{\Bbb Q}(x) - g(n,x)\rvert = 0$ for all $x$ in $D$, $D$ being set of all irrationals plus all rationals with denominator less or equal to $n$. As $n$ goes to infinity, $D$ goes to $\Bbb R$. Without using $D$ in the definition, Dirichlet function can not be approximated by Riemann-integrable functions with $\varepsilon < 1/3$.

Comment: In what sense do you want functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be approximated by continuumly many functions?

Comment: I can’t make sense of what’s the point of quantifying over $D\ne\mathbb R$, as approximating functions on $D=\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}$ is essentially the same as approximating functions on $\mathbb R$. Ignoring that, picking for each $n\in\mathbb N$ a $g_n\in S$ such that $|f(x)-g_n(x)|<1/n$ for all $x$, we have that $f$ is uniquely determined as the pointwise limit of the $g_n$’s. Thus, if this is possible for all functions $f$, we have $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}=|\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}|\le|S|^{\aleph_0}$, which certainly implies $|S|>2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Edits are not supposed to try to explain what the original poster had in mind, @user479568 – that's the job of the original poster. The question is now 80% your writing!

Comment: After all, the closure of a set $S$ in a metric space has not larger cardinality than the set  $S^\mathbb N$ of all sequences in $S$. So if #S= *c*, the cardinality of the closure remains *c*.

Answer (score 4):

Every set of functions $S$ with the required approximation property must have cardinality $2^{\bf c}$, where ${\bf c=}2^{{\aleph}_0}$ is the cardinality of the continuum.

Fix a set $D \ne \mathbb R$ on the line with   cardinality  ${\bf c}$, and let $\epsilon<1/3$.
Let
$$S_D=\{f \in S: f(D) \subset (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \cup (1-\epsilon,,1+\epsilon) \}\,.$$
Let $R(y)$ be the nearest integer to $y$, rounding up to break ties.
The map $f \mapsto R\circ f|_D$ is surjective from $S_D$ onto $\{0,1\}^D$,
so the cardinality of $S$ is at least $2^{\bf c}$.

It follows that the cardinality of $S$ equals $2^c$.

Comment: This argument is not quite correct, since knowing only that $D$ is uncountable, it doesn't follow that $2^D$ has size larger than continuum. Indeed, it is consistent with ZFC that $2^D$ can equal the continuum. For example, under Luzin's hypothesis, $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$. But your argument would be fixed by taking $D$ of size continuum, rather than merely uncountable, since $2^{\frak{c}}$ is always larger than $\frak{c}$.

Comment: Thank you, corrected now.